# How to search and display name in ascending or descending with browser

Tags: progress-4gl

when i search in the name fill-in with a starting letter of a name it should display all the name starting with that letter.

TIP: it should use open query`

```
DO:
    IF (input customer.cust-num <> 0)  and (input customer.name = "")  then do:
        find first customer where ( customer.cust-num = input cust-num) no-error.
        OPEN QUERY custqry FOR EACH customer.
        display customer.cust-num customer.name customer.balance customer.discount customer.credit-limit customer.phone customer.contact with browse br1 . /*to display in browser*/
        assign
            ocustnum      = customer.cust-num
            oName         = customer.Name
            obalance      = customer.balance
            odiscount     = customer.discount
            ocredit-limit = customer.credit-limit
            ophone        = customer.phone
            ocontact      = customer.contact .
        display ocustnum oName obalance odiscount ocredit-limit ophone ocontact with frame default-frame  . /*to display in fillin*/
    end.
    ELSE IF (input customer.cust-num = 0)  and (input customer.name <> "") then do:
        find first customer where customer.name begins input name no-error .
        OPEN QUERY q FOR EACH customer BY name.     
        display customer.cust-num customer.name customer.balance customer.discount customer.credit-limit customer.phone customer.contact with browse br1. /*to display in browser*/
        assign
            ocustnum      = customer.cust-num
            oName         = customer.Name
            obalance      = customer.balance
            odiscount     = customer.discount
            ocredit-limit = customer.credit-limit
            ophone        = customer.phone
            ocontact      = customer.contact .
        display ocustnum oName obalance odiscount ocredit-limit ophone ocontact with frame default-frame  . /*to display in fillin*/   
    end.      
    ELSE IF (input customer.cust-num <> 0)  and (input customer.name <> "") then do:  
        find first customer where ( customer.cust-num = input cust-num) and (customer.name begins input name) no-lock  no-error .
        OPEN QUERY cust-query FOR EACH customer BY name.
        display customer.cust-num customer.name customer.balance customer.discount customer.credit-limit customer.phone customer.contact with browse br1. /*to display in browser*/
        assign
            ocustnum      = customer.cust-num
            oName         = customer.Name
            obalance      = customer.balance
            odiscount     = customer.discount
            ocredit-limit = customer.credit-limit
            ophone        = customer.phone
            ocontact      = customer.contact .
        display ocustnum oName obalance odiscount ocredit-limit ophone ocontact with frame default-frame  . /*to display in fillin*/   
   end.  
END.
```

`
the above code i have written for the search button.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5IQA.png)

Comment: If you want it to display only names that start with the code that's being typed in, you might want to change it to the browse query. So I thought you're finding a customer before, I don't really get why you'd take the time to do that if you're not acting on it.
If you're in AppBuilder, you might want to try 
    OPEN QUERY {&browse-name} for each customer where customer.name begins input cust-num.

Answer (score 0):

Use BEGINS to match the start of a string and use BY to control sorting order:

```
OPEN QUERY q FOR EACH customer 
                WHERE customer.name BEGINS (INPUT customer.name) BY name.
```